# Hide Rows When Data Not Match With The Search Criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code to search the data based on the user input.
I wanted to hide those rows not match so that users can have a better view.
My Data start from Row 7. Thanks.

```
Sub find_highlight1() 'Unhide and go to the 1st sheet found the data

Dim FindString As String
Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
Dim FoundCell As Range
Dim FirstAddress As String
Dim countfound As Integer
Dim sheetactive As Integer

countfound = 0
sheetactive = 0

FindString = InputBox("Please Key in the Number You Wish to Search")
If FindString = "" Then Exit Sub

'Use For...Each to cycle through the Worksheets collection.
For Each wrkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    'Find the first instance on the sheet.
    Set FoundCell = wrkSht.Cells.Find(What:=FindString, After:=wrkSht.Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

     'Check it found something.
     If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
         'Save the first address as FIND loops around to the start
         FirstAddress = FoundCell.Address
         wrkSht.Visible = xlSheetVisible 'Unhide worksheet where found
         countfound = countfound + 1
         sheetactive = sheetactive + 1
         If sheetactive <= 1 Then
          wrkSht.Select
     End If

        Do
             With FoundCell.Interior
                 .ColorIndex = 6
                 .Pattern = xlSolid
                 .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic

             End With
             'Look for the next instance on the same sheet.
            Set FoundCell = wrkSht.Cells.FindNext(FoundCell)
         Loop While FoundCell.Address <> FirstAddress
     End If

 Next wrkSht

End Sub`
```

[image]

Comment: `Range.AutoFilter` is the best / easiest method in this case.

Comment: Yes! What Scott said. Something like this: `MyRange.AutoFilter 1, "=[ValueToKeepVisible]"`. `1` is the `Field` or `Column` to filter.

Comment: I tried wrkSht.Range("$A$6:$Z$1000").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="FindString" but all rows will be hidden, where goes wrong? and then also how to unfilter them say when I return or go to another sheet?

Comment: I think my question may be unclear, the search can be any column and not restricted to column 3 only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this within your code (add your other code with the Input Box to capture the `FindString`):

```
    Dim StringValueColumn as long

    StringValueColumn = wrkSht.Cells.Find(What:=FindString, After:=wrkSht.Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column

    MyRange.AutoFilter StringValueColumn, "=[ValueToKeepVisible]"
```

**Update**

Something simple like this will work.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FilterRows()

    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim FindString As String
    Dim FindRange As Range

    Set MyRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    FindString = InputBox("Type a Value")

    Set FindRange = MyRange.Find(What:=FindString)
    If Not FindRange Is Nothing Then
        MyRange.AutoFilter FindRange.Column, FindString
    End If

End Sub
```

**Sample Data**

```
Range("A1:C4")

First       Middle      Last  'Header Values
Brian       Daniel      Smith
Larry       Amos        Smith
Tanya       Esther      Schmidt
```

Comment: Thanks. added a sub but not working and still trying to debug.

Comment: I added this line just below that Do statement - wrkSht.Rows("7").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=FindString but this only allows me to filter column H. Tried your statement no luck, not sure where goes wrong. I still trying to figure out how to apply the code to all the column instead of just one. else when user do a search of other data (not H column), may have run-time errors.

Comment: My code should work on all the columns. Paste my sample data and use the code on it. Type Larry. Then type Smith. It won't be the final code. I'm just demonstrating a simple technique you can tailor to your needs.

Comment: Yes, your code is working, but when trying to put on the dashboard to check thru the workbook with multi sheets, it will not work. Still trying to figure it.

Comment: Thanks, Brian, I managed to solve it. Much appreciate your help and advise.